# AWS SNS: How to prevent AWS from throwing an Internal Server Error when an ARN is disabled?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-sns

I am writing a Push Notification service with AWS. A User can have multiple devices registered for receiving notifications.

I store each ARN (Amazon Resource Name) in DynamoDB. When a notification is being sent to a User, I obtain all ARNs and publish a notification to each.

However, at some point, an ARN can become *disabled*. That of course means that a notification cannot be sent to this specific device.

How can I use the `aws-sdk` to determine whether an Endpoint is enabled/disabled before attempting to send a notification?

Right now, I get a `HTTP 502 Internal Server Error` response.

CloudWatch logs:

```
018-02-21T16:31:03.742Z 9bc412f6-1724-11e8-aa7b-596b69243ced    { 
EndpointDisabled: Endpoint is disabled .
...
message: 'Endpoint is disabled',
code: 'EndpointDisabled',
time: 2018-02-21T16:31:03.742Z,
requestId: '6217ac24-89f4-5be5-b6da-ff2328f3cdf4',
statusCode: 400,
retryable: false,
retryDelay: 24.93677139755519 }
```

My service stack:

- API Gateway
- AWS Lambda
- DynamoDB
- AWS SNS

As previously mentioned, I am using `aws-sdk`.

Comment: It looks as if you are doing `callback(error, ...` when this occurs.  Are you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWS.SNS.getEndpointAttributes():

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SNS.html#getEndpointAttributes-property

```
var params = {
  EndpointArn: 'STRING_VALUE' /* required */
};
sns.getEndpointAttributes(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

This returns several attributes including the `Enabled` flag:

```
Enabled -- flag that enables/disables delivery to the endpoint. Amazon SNS
will set this to false when a notification service indicates to Amazon SNS
that the endpoint is invalid. Users can set it back to true, typically after
updating Token.
```